# Conditional logic no longer working as expected?

Tags: powershell, logic

Its been a long day and I think I'm going mad. I wanted to test for a file and generate an email if none existed. Here it is pared down to its most minimal:

```
> IF('False' -eq (Test-Path D:\Scripts\SFTP\Import\*)){ECHO "SEND EMAIL"}
> SEND EMAIL

__________________________________________________________________________
> IF((Test-Path D:\Scripts\SFTP\Import\*) -eq 'False'){ECHO "SEND EMAIL"}
>
```

Why doesn't the second command work?

I've tried running the `Test-Path` outside of the 'IF' statement into a variable and then testing against that, again it doesn't work.

If I simply run the 'Test-Path' command I get a boolean 'False' as expected. I've used conditional logic in this way before and its worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is this. In the first one you have a string as the first operand of the comparison. This forces PS to coerce the second operand to a string if possible. In this case that means calling the `.ToString()` method of the boolean which would return the 'False' string (if the boolean is actually false of course). In the second case though, you are presenting a boolean as the first operand, so the string is being coerced to a boolean. Obviously it is not working. To avoid these issues, use the builtin `$false` (or `$true`) variable. Personally I would suggest just negating the `Test-Path`. Here are a couple of ways that should work:

```
if( -NOT (Test-Path D:\Scripts\SFTP\Import\*)){


if( (Test-Path D:\Scripts\SFTP\Import\*) -eq $false){
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Seems to be working now. The question I have now is how I have managed to get almost identical tests working in other scripts I've written.

Comment: I would need to see the other bits to say.

Answer (score 1):

For the coercing rules of powershell

```
'False' -eq (Test-Path D:\Scripts\SFTP\Import\*)
```

the second value of comparision is evaluated as [string]

here

```
(Test-Path D:\Scripts\SFTP\Import\*) -eq 'False'
```

the second value of comparison can't be evaluated as [Bool] then it fails.

For bool comparin is optima use the automatic variable `$false` and `$true`